# anchor positioning browsers

Tags: html, css

I am using the following html to position anchors under a fixed menu:

```
<a style="position: relative; top: -150px;" name="services"></a>
```

This works fine in Firefox but ie, chrome and safari all load the anchors to a slightly different position, obscuring the text 'under' the fixed menu.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could go about resolving this issue.

wip site is http://mattangel.com.au

Many thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

When I make sites like this, I like to make sure that each "page" has a similar class, but different id. When styling the class, make sure you give the following attributes.

```
.page {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 1000px;
}
```

Adding the margin-bottom will prevent you from seeing the extra pages.

I also noticed that you are using jQuery for the slide to effect, I am not sure why you are using the styling for the a name. Just do the following:

```
<h1 class="page_title" id="services"><a name="services">Services</a></h1>
```

And make sure to wrap everything up in the page DIV.